# why doesn't my vb code stop on a stop statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am maintaining some VB code that does not seem to stop on a stop statement.

When I run the program under certain conditions, this code throws the System.Exception("Timed out") from the last line of code.

But if you go thru the code line-by-line, it seems like it can never hit this statement. First it tries to Return MyBase.Save. If it can't, then it will hits the stop statement and stop.

But it seems like the program is just skipping the stop statement.

How can I  debug this code? Specifically, how does it skip the stop statement to get to the statement Throw New System.Exception("Timed out")

```
Public Overrides Function Save() As Uber

    If IsDeleted AndAlso Not CanDeleteObject() Then
        Throw New System.Security.SecurityException("User is not authorized to remove a Uber")
    ElseIf IsNew AndAlso Not CanAddObject() Then
        Throw New System.Security.SecurityException("User is not authorized to add a Uber")
    ElseIf Not IsNew AndAlso Not CanEditObject() Then
        Throw New System.Security.SecurityException("User is not authorized to update a Uber")
    End If

    Try
        Return MyBase.Save
    Catch ex As Exception

        Stop   //why is the code not stopping here?
    End Try

    Throw New System.Exception("Timed out")  //this line executes, but I don't see how the code gets there

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Stop only creates a breakpoint for debugging.

The execution of the code will continue.

I think an exception is being thrown in Return MyBase.Save. It's being caught in the Catch block but it is effectively being ignored by that block because ex is never used.

Comment: @hatchet the link in your comment says that when not debugging, Stop acts like End. It terminates execution. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: @MarkJ - that's a good observation. I guess it depends on what the OP meant by "When I run the program under certain conditions".